# Is there a way that I can make my code return back to my UserChoice menu in C#?

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I am currently new to C#, so I am not too familiar with some of the commands, methods, and syntax. I am currently making a medical program where I am asking the user to input their horse data, and vaccinations records and with the vaccination records I made it loop so if the user has more than one vaccination record they can add it and if the user does not have any more data to input they can type 0 but there is a problem with the it, when the user types 0 it does not return back to the main menu instead it still asks the user to still input vaccination record instead of breaking the loop. Also, it does not store the records; it's like everything defaults back to zero or none. Please can someone help me and walk me through it too so when I encounter something like this again in the future, I will be able to refer to it. Thank you so much for your help

Here is my code

```
 switch (UserChoice)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter New Horse");
                    myHorse = AddHorse();
                    myHorse.PrintHorseInfo();
                    HorseList.Add(myHorse);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Delete Horse");
                    Console.WriteLine("What Horse do you want to delete");
                    string aResponse = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Are you sure you want to delete");
                    string Response = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (Response.ToUpper() == "YES") 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You are now entering the deletion zone");
                        int i = HorseList.IndexOf(myHorse);
                        HorseList.RemoveAt(i);
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"{myHorse.Name} has been deleted");
                        }     
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("returning to the main menu");
                    }

                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("View all horses");
                    foreach (Horse h in HorseList)
                    {
                        h.PrintHorseInfo();
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Quit");
                    Environment.Exit(0);

                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Choose an option to start");
                    break;
            }

static Horse AddHorse()
    {
        Horse myHorse = new Horse();
        Horse newHorse = null;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your horse's common name");
        String pName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your horse's registered name");
        String regName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your horses breed");
        String pBreed = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("What year was your horse born?");
        String pAge = Console.ReadLine();
        int YearOfBirth;
        Console.WriteLine("What is the size of your horse?");
        String pSize = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Input your horse's vaccination record or enter 0 to exit.");

        String iD = Console.ReadLine();

        while (iD.Equals("0"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input Vaccination Date");
            String vacDate = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Input your horse's vaccination record or enter 0 to exit.");
            iD = Console.ReadLine();
            if (iD == "0")
            {
                break;
            }
            
            
        }
```

Here is my part of my Horse Class for the vaccinations records

```
Hashtable vaccination_records =  new Hashtable();

 public string getVacs()
        {
            String vacString = "Vac Records";
            foreach (DictionaryEntry Vac in vaccination_records)
            {
                vacString = vacString + " " + Vac.Key + "-" + Vac.Value + "\n";
            }
            return vacString;
        }
        


        public void AddVac(string VacId, string LastDateVac)
        {
            vaccination_records.Add(VacId, LastDateVac);
        }
```

Output:

[image: Here is my output to my code]

With my first attempt I tried to see if I can use Enviroment.exit() method and I saw that it exited the entire program so I went back to the cutting board and tried to see if a break might work but that did not work so I tried to see if an If statement might be the one but I did not know how to set to make it do what I wanted it to do. Like I did not know what to type inside of my if statement :/

Comment: You are lucky!!!  One of my first projects in college was a similar data entry program.  The teacher had two online files for inputs.  One had no errors and the other had errors (like an input of 5 when app only had 4 choices).  I finally got first no error input to run.  Then to get the input with errors to work I had to keep on modifying the code.  We were using punch cards.  Program was about 500 cards.  Ended up with twice that number in the circular basket, garbage can.   Best way of learning is from your own mistakes.

Comment: The issue in this case is not the program, it is the design of the input statements.  You cannot change the inputs structure.  Designing a more robust input structure will make it easier to code and not get stuck in loops.  Or create a two pass parser.  First check for errors and then do processing.  If errors exist just through out the entire input.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you have several problems.

First of all if you want to entirely skip Vaccination block then you shoud to check that user input NOT equals to zero because the loop will be executed as long as the loop condition is true.

```
while (iD != "0")
```

Also you should save vaccinations records to `myHorse` object each time inside the loop before you exit the loop with `break` statement:

```
String vacDate = Console.ReadLine();
newHorse.AddVac(iD, vacDate);
```

Finally you store all parameters in the separated variables. But you never add them to the `myHorse` object. Your final code might look something like this:

```
static Horse AddHorse()
{
    Horse myHorse = new Horse();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your horse's common name");
    myHorse.Name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your horse's registered name");
    myHorse.RegName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your horses breed");
    myHorse.Breed = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("What year was your horse born?");
    myHorse.Age = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("What is the size of your horse?");
    myHorse.Size = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Input your horse's vaccination record or enter 0 to exit.");
    String iD = Console.ReadLine();

    while (iD != "0")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input Vaccination Date");
        String vacDate = Console.ReadLine();
        myHorse.AddVac(iD, vacDate);
    
        Console.WriteLine("Input your horse's vaccination record or enter 0 to exit.");
        iD = Console.ReadLine();
        // you don't need to check iD here 
        // because it will already be checked in the loop condition
    }

    return myHorse;
}
```